Issue with Airflow to Airbyte Connection via host.docker.internal
I have been doing some online workshops and tutorials on creating data pipelines, mainly with Apache Airflow and Airbyte via Docker. This issue I am experiencing is establishing the connection between Airflow and Airbyte. I have read several posts which have a similar issue and read through respective documentation on both Airflow and Airbyte but the issue persists despite my change attempts.
Is there something wrong with how I have set up my connection? Does anyone have a different configuration (with versions noted) which is confirmed working?
System Configuration

Windows 10 OS
Docker Desktop v4.34.3 (170107)
Apache Airflow v2.8.3 (but I have tested both 2.10.3 and latest)
Airbyte v0.63.13

Additional Setup Notes

Airflow webserver is set on port 8080
Airbyte is set on port 8000
In the docker-compose.yaml file, both the Airflow webserver and scheduler have "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" in the extra_hosts field.

Airflow to Airbyte Connection

When comparing to connection setups online, I cannot use the Airbyte version as the port field is not available. Hence, I am using a HTTP connection which should work.

HTTP Connection Setup
Airbyte Connection Template which has no port field
Error Log (running airflow dag)
f213ecff2dd7
*** Found logs served from host http://f213ecff2dd7:8793/log/dag_id=elt_and_dbt/run_id=manual__2024-11-10T10:19:32.960623+00:00/task_id=airbyte_postgres_postgres/attempt=1.log
[2024-11-10, 10:19:43 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:123} ▶ Pre task execution logs
[2024-11-10, 10:19:43 UTC] {base.py:84} INFO - Retrieving connection 'airbyte'
[2024-11-10, 10:19:43 UTC] {taskinstance.py:3311} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/airbyte/hooks/airbyte.py", line 157, in submit_sync_connection
    res = self.airbyte_api.jobs.create_job(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airbyte_api/jobs.py", line 100, in create_job
    raise e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airbyte_api/jobs.py", line 94, in create_job
    req = client.prepare_request(requests_http.Request('POST', url, params=query_params, data=data, files=form, headers=headers))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 484, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 367, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 438, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'host.docker.internal/jobs': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://host.docker.internal/jobs?
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 767, in _execute_task
    result = _execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 733, in _execute_callable
    return ExecutionCallableRunner(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/utils/operator_helpers.py", line 252, in run
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 417, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/airbyte/operators/airbyte.py", line 83, in execute
    job_object = hook.submit_sync_connection(connection_id=self.connection_id)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/airbyte/hooks/airbyte.py", line 165, in submit_sync_connection
    raise AirflowException(e)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid URL 'host.docker.internal/jobs': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://host.docker.internal/jobs?
[2024-11-10, 10:19:43 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1225} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=elt_and_dbt, task_id=airbyte_postgres_postgres, run_id=manual__2024-11-10T10:19:32.960623+00:00, execution_date=20241110T101932, start_date=20241110T101943, end_date=20241110T101943
[2024-11-10, 10:19:43 UTC] {taskinstance.py:340} ▶ Post task execution logs

Code Snippet of dag file, showing only Airbyte components for reference
from airflow import DAG
from docker.types import Mount
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.airbyte.operators.airbyte import AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

# Acquiring connection ID from Airbyte UI
CONN_ID = '594c2ffe-fe0e-4ccb-9c29-c02f4a9fb2bd'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
}

dag = DAG(
    'elt_and_dbt',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='An ELT workflow with dbt',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    catchup=False
)

t1 = AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator(
    task_id='airbyte_postgres_postgres',
    airbyte_conn_id='airbyte',
    connection_id=CONN_ID,
    asynchronous=False,
    timeout=3600,
    wait_seconds=3,
    dag=dag
)


I tried deleting the containers, volumes and images related to Airflow and install different versions e.g., 2.10.3, latest. However, the issue persists. I have not tried re-installing Airbyte since my connection to the databases (also using host.docker.internal) are successful.
For the host field of the Airflow to Airbyte Connection, I have tried both 'host.docker.internal' and 'localhost' (reviewing documentation and other posts) but neither one works.
Given my setup is a HTTP template, I also did try 'https://host.docker.internal' but I get different error (below) which suggests the connection setting is incorrect.

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/applications/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa52e062990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Are both components running in containers?  You should not need host.docker.internal or any of its associated setup in this case.  (Imagine trying to print something on your home network, but sending the print job to your router to forward it to the printer, instead of just sending it directly to the printer.)

Yes, both Airflow and Airbyte are running in containers. From my code snippet, AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator will need a connection id which is what is needed to establish in the connection setup of the Airflow UI. I can try commenting the reference but I don't think this would work ...

How did you launch the two containers?  If they're both in the same Compose file, you can use the Compose service names as host names; maybe something like http://airbyte:8000 will work.  The actual error message suggests you need a full URL with a scheme and not just a host name, and if you're not using port 80, you also need to specify the TCP port number.

Both Airflow and Airbyte are in separate folders in the same project workspace and have their own separate docker compose files. I've used a bash script to automate the startup of the containers. So as they are separate containers in docker, I would think they all share the same host. Using the HTTP setup, I do agree it needs a full URL with a schema but online documentation has not been useful. I will keep on digging for now. Thanks.

I had the same issue.
In my case, I needed to connect the isolated container with Airflow's network using the command:
docker network connect network container

Then, I had to get the IP of the Airbyte container:
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name

You should retrieve the internal IP of the Airbyte container. After that, create a connection in Airflow using the internal IP you obtained with the Docker command. For me, this worked perfectly.
